# Trying to understand when to use nested routes vs. when not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Blog < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

Right now I have only two routes:

- `/blogs/:blog_id/posts` - to create a post
- `/posts/id:` - to update a post

I'm not sure if I should change the second one to also accept a `:blog_id`. The update method (on the controller) doesn't need to use the site to update a post:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_site, only: [:create]
  before_action :set_post, only: [:update]

  PERMITED_POST_PARAMS = [
    :post_id,
    :title,
    :url,
    :body
  ].freeze

  def create
    @post = @site.posts.build(post_params)

    if @post.save
      render json: @post, status: :created
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      render json: @post
    else
      render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(*PERMITED_POST_PARAMS)
  end

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(id)
  end

  def set_site
    @site = Site.find(site_id)
  end

  def post_id
    params[:post_id]
  end

  def id
    params[:id]
  end
end
```

My question is: is it ok to do what I'm doing, or it a bad practice?

Thank you.

Comment: While I feel like this question is probably an opinion based question (and the 2 current answers start with "In my opinion" and "it depends"), I will leave a link to this tidbit about [shallow nesting](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#shallow-nesting) in the rails guide on routing with my VTC

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answer is more like an opinion, but I'd say yes - keep it simple.

To create a post you need a `:blog_id` so a nested resource is one way to do it. Other would be `POST /post` and pass the `:blog_id` in the POST params.

Both seem perfectly fine, and it's up to you to design your API. The biggest rule: keep it consistent.

That being said - I can't recall single API that I was using, which used the nested resources for the create/update methods. It seems awkward: if I create a post - why one attribute of it (`blog_id`) should go in the path, and rest should be sent as params?

On the other hand nested resources work great for the read methods: 
`/post/1/comments` instead of `/comments?post_id=1`

Is has more natural fell to it - access resource `/post/1` and subresources as a sub path `/post/1/author`, `/post/1/tags`

But create resources directly `POST /tags`, `post /comments` with the attributes passed on as params.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends. It's ok to do what you want, it's also ok to have the update nested inside the other model (it's confusing that you have "blog_id" on the route and your helpers are "post_id" and "id" but you call "id" to find a post and "site_id" which is not defined (??)).

Rails route helpers will automatically create the update nested inside the site if you do something like:

```
resources :blogs do
  resources :posts
end
```

You don't really need the blog_id, but you can use that as an extra filtering measure: if you have the blog_id, you can do `@post = @blog.posts.find(...)` instead of `@post = Post.find(...)`.

Is it needed? no, but it gives you context and consistency on your routes (really opinionable of course).

(Why are you permitting post_id??)

Comment: `post_id` is actually something else. I will rename it so it doesn't cause this type of confusion.